# Как скопировать в txt в кодировке ANSI смайлик (эмодзи)?

Tags: кодировка, ansi, emoji

Есть .txt в кодировке ANSI, вставляю туда смайлик, например , получаю после сохранения `??`

Есть возможность копировать в .txt смайлики без потерь и копировать их так же из .txt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, есть, но не в кодировках, обычно понимающихся под ANSI.

Эмодзи - это часть [Юникода](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4), основной кодировкой для которого является UTF-8. ANSI - это широкий термин, который может включать в себя и просто ASCII, и [всевозможные расширенные восьмибитные кодировки](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_character_set). В последнем случае можно сказать что то, что вы наблюдаете - ожидаемое явления в случае если вы пытаетесь сохранить какой-то символ в кодировке, в которой этого символа нет (можно представить что первым приближением [для � `U+FFFD`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)) будет знак вопроса).

Таким образом, основной практический вариант сохранить эмодзи и смайлики - использовать совместимую с ними кодировку вроде всем привычной UTF-8.

Если же говорить о сохранении данных для отображения в браузере, то можно сохранять эмодзи в HTML-закодированном виде. Например, для  это будет `&#x1f499;`. Это не самый лучший способ со всех точек зрения, но если иного выхода нет - то это вариант.